# Delete files, copy the same named files from another folder C#

Tags: c#, replace, copy

I have several issues within a windows forms application. So far, I have managed to loop though a folder and display the reuslts in a text box. Once these have returned, the user can check the results and the error files can be removed using the following;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\" + textBox1.Text + @"\\d$\\NSB\\Coalition\\EDU", "*.err").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".err")))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

What I want to do now, after the error files have been removed, is copy the same files from a backup folder (the only difference in the filenames is the file extention) I am using a seperate button for this action. Any help on this final step would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just move and overwrite the files?.. Plenty of research material on this too

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. The error files do not always require replacing within the folder. Sometimes they only need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Path class to get File names without extensions, combine paths and more, as an example:

```
StringCollection filesToBeReplaced = new StringCollection();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\" + textBox1.Text +      @"\\d$\\NSB\\Coalition\\EDU", "*.err").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".err")))
{
  //Now you have file names without extension        
  filesToBeReplaced.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (file));
      File.Delete(file);
  }
}
private void CopyGoodFilesFromSource()
{
  foreach(string fileName in filesToBeReplaced)
  {
     string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine("YOUR FOLDER FOR GOOD FILES", 
Path.ChangeExtension(fileName,"Your Extension")) ;
      string destinationPath = Path.Combine("Destination Folder",
Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "Your Extension in destination folder");

     File.Copy(sourceFilePath , destinationPath, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad i was able to help :)